# What should I index in my grandfathers autobiography?

Tags: indexing, autobiography

Several years ago (before his death) my grandfather was writing his memoirs. I am now attempting to compile the multiple document he wrote in to one quasi-autobiography. I understand that most biographies have some form of index, but I am unsure what things I should be adding to the index.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I would add the names of people, places and significant events e.g. marriages. Depending on how you organise the text, you may want to include themes, but if it is chronological you probably don't need to include dates.